# react native app crashes with error create realm

Tags: react-native, realm, realm-mobile-platform

XHR failed loading: POST "http://localhost:8083/create_realm".

am seeing this when I launch my app, I had modified the realm once, bt removed it

this is my realm code

static getInstance() {
var dbName = `${AuthService.bidderNumber}.realm`;
var realm = new Realm({ path: dbName, schema: [ListingSchema, LotSchema], deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded: true });
return realm;